# Proper way of closing Streams in Java Sockets

Tags: java, android, sockets, inputstream

I saw some posts about this but I still can't find an answer.

This is how my server interacts with the client:

```
public void run () {
    try {
        //Read client request
        InputStream is = server.getInputStream();
        byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
        int i;
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        while ((i = is.read(buff, 0, buff.length)) != -1) {
            bos.write(buff, 0, i);
            System.out.println(i + " bytes readed ("+bos.size()+")");
        }
        is.close();
        is = null;
        //Do something with client request

        //write response
        OutputStream os = server.getOutputStream();
        os.write("server response".getBytes());
        os.flush();
        os.close();
        os = null;

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And this is the client side:

```
public void run() {
        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = null;
            serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("10.0.2.2");
            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, 5000);

            //Send Request to the server
            OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
            os.write(jsonRequest.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
            os.flush();
            os.close();
            os = null;

            //Read Server Response
            InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
            byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
            int i;
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            while ((i = is.read(buff, 0, buff.length)) != -1) {
                bos.write(buff, 0, i);
                System.out.println(i + " bytes readed ("+bos.size()+")");
            }
            is.close();
            is = null;

            //Do something with server response

        } catch (UnknownHostException uhe) {
            sendCallbackError(uhe);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            sendCallbackError(ioe);
        }
    }
```

As you can see, the client connects and send a request. Server read that request then writes a response that the client will read.

The problem with this code is the `OutputStream.close()` in the client and `InputStream.close()` in the server. As stated in the Javadocs, closing the stream will close the `Socket`. The result is that when the client tries to read the server response, the `Socket` is already closed.

I've managed to overcome this by calling `Socket.shutdownInput` and `Socket.shutdownOutput` instead. However I am still thinking whether this is the proper way of doing it

As a note, closing the streams with `close()` when server writes the response or when the client reads it doesn't create problems (I would guess the closing is synchronized between client and server).

So my questions are:

1. Is using the Socket shutdown methods a proper way?
2. Can I keep closing the last streams with `close()` (when sending and reading
   response from server)
3. Could it happen that closing with shutdown would keep some data in
   the buffer and wouldn't be sent?

Comment: put socket.close() in a finally block.

Comment: @PeterLawrey do you mean not closing the streams and close the socket instead? If yes, I guess I should close the socket in both ends, right?

Comment: You should close the sockets, if you want to flush the output stream first you might want to close or flush it first.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I am confused. Javadocs clearly says (and this code proves it) that the Socket is closed when the Stream is closed. Do you mean something like Norton said below: in a finally block close the streams and then close the socket?

Comment: You only need to close the stream if you have a BufferedOuptutStream and this has unsent data (in the buffer)  If this is not the case, juts closing the socket is all you need. If you close the socket and there is unsent data, this will never be sent.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
try{
}catch(){
}finally{
if(is!=null){
is.close();
}
if(os!=null){
os.close();
}
}
```

Comment: This is a simplified example. The Streams are actually being created in different methods that are called from the run() method. So I really have no access to the variables unless I declare them as member variables of the Runnable class

Comment: Tried your suggestion. It's not working for me because if the client's OutputStream is not closed/shutdown the server keeps reading eternally. Maybe I should send a termination sequence to finish the reading...

Answer (score 0):

> The problem with this code is the OutputStream.close() in the client and InputStream.close() in the server. As stated in the Javadocs, closing the stream will close the Socket.

Correct but the `InputStream` in the server isn't connected directly to a `Socket:` it is connected to something you don't know anything about. You can close it with impunity, although again you don't need to close it at all. You can close the `OutputStream` in the server if you like: although, again, as it isn't connected directly to a `Socket,` it may or may not have any effect other than flushing.

To address your actual question, you don't need to close the output stream in the client, but you do need to send an appropriate Content-Length: header. That way the server knows how much to read from the client. If this is only a GET request the content-length may well be zero. You don't need to call `shutdownOutput(),` although I guess there is nothing to stop you, and calling `shutdownInput()` doesn't do anything to the network anyway so again there is no point to it.

Comment: while you are maybe right about the InputStream in the server, if I close it and then try to open the OutputStream, it will fail with a Socket Closed IOException. 
Regarding the Content-Length, I understand you mean reserving the first bytes of the byte array to specify the message length, right? I think that should be the best solution because the way I break the reading in the server (read() != -1) won't be triggered unless I close() the OutputStream in the server or call socket.shutdownOutput(). The latest is working just fine.

Comment: (1) So don't close it then. Closing it or not has nothing to do with with your question. (2) No, I am referring to the HTTP Content-Length header. Look it up.

Comment: This is a plain socket connection sending JSON in plain old bytes, that's the only protocol implemented. I have no idea how an HTTP header could fit in this implementation...